# Marking non monotonically increasing data

Tags: r, vector, cumulative-sum

Dear colleagues I have a data-frame containing values for a cumulative sensor that sometimes goes to 0 due to data quality problems.

I am aware that you can check if the values fulfill the monotonically increasing condition as follows:

```
all(test[, 2] >= cummax(test[, 2]))
```

I was trying to get the marker with which but it does not work.

```
which(all(test[, 2] >= cummax(test[, 2])))
```

Then I was trying to use the package [MonoInc](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/MonoInc/MonoInc.pdf) but I am getting the following error:

```
mono.flag(test, x.col=3, y.col=4, direction = 'inc', min=0, max(test$snsr_val))
Error: Positive column indexes in `[` must match number of columns:
* `.data` has 8 columns
* Position 1 equals 55237
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

With the back trace:

```
> rlang::last_trace()
    x
 1. \-MonoInc::mono.flag(...)
 2.   +-base::cbind(data[, id.col], data[, x.col], data[, y.col])
 3.   +-data[, id.col]
 4.   \-tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(data, , id.col)
 5.     \-tibble:::check_names_df(j, x)
 6.       \-tibble:::check_names_df_numeric(j, x)
>
```

Does someone else know how to do the same task using another method?

BR
/E

Comment: Please add `test[, 2]` and the expected output to your question.

Comment: `which(test[-1, 2] < test[-nrow(test), 2] + 1`?

Comment: @Ben373 No, `which(test[-1, 2] < test[-nrow(test), 2]) + 1`.